# how to create new instances of a class for each asynchronus call (made using CompletableFuture)

Tags: java, completable-future

Here is my code:

```
   class A{
    @Autowired
    B objB;

   public method1(){
       List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
       ids.add("1");
       ids.add("2");
       ids.add("3");
       List<CompletableFuture<String>> listOfFuture ids.stream()
                        .map(id -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                                  objB.method2(id)).collect(toList());
   }
}

    class B{
    @Inject
    D objD;
    @Inject
    E objE

    public String method2(String id){
        String transformedId = objD.method3(id);
        return objE.method4(transformedId);
    }
}
```

class B has method2 has objects which are not thread safe. I want to make new instances of B so that each thread has its own objects while executing method2. I can use spring's async utility for method2 and call this method asynchronously from A instead of using CompletableFuture in class A. This will make method2 thread safe. How can I make method2 thread safe if I used CompletableFuture?
Is my assumption correct that I need different object for Class B every time I spawn a thread to invoke method2 since class B is not thread safe?

Comment: Use constructor injection and make sure that each class A instance has its own injected instance of class B.  If you pass the instance of class B into the method, it'll be as thread safe as the object that passes it in.

Comment: Shared, mutable data is the issue.  Get rid of all state in class A.  Pass the instance of class B as a parameter into method() and you're thread safe.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd recommend you do it:

```
 class A{


   public method1(B objB){
       List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
       ids.add("1");
       ids.add("2");
       ids.add("3");
       List<CompletableFuture<String>> listOfFuture ids.stream()
                        .map(id -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                                  objB.method2(id)).collect(toList());
   }
}
```

This is thread safe because there's no shared mutable data.  The parameters passed into each method are independent.

Comment: This does not solve the problem since all the thread spawned by fork-join pool for CompletableFuture is still going to use  same objB. I need a different instance of B every time method2 is invoked.

Comment: No, it's going to use the reference to the object that you pass to the method each time.   Pass a different reference when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by setting scope of a bean as prototype. It is not the best way but we could do this way also

```
@Component
class A implements ApplicationContextAware {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        public void method1() {
            List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
            ids.add("1");
            ids.add("2");
            ids.add("3");
            List<CompletableFuture<String>> listOfFuture = ids.stream()
                    .map(id -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> applicationContext.getBean(B.class).method2(id)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

        }
    }

    @Component("beanB")
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    class B {
        public String method2(String id) {
            // Your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is my assumption correct that I need different object for Class B every time I spawn a thread to invoke method2 since class B is not thread safe?

Comment: If class B is not thread safe then either you have to make it thread safe or create new object for every thread.  But I think best practice would be to make class b thread safe by removing shared state if possible.